# A module that has a composition series is both Artinian and Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that the proof is quite easy, but there is something I don't understand. Suppose that $M$ is an $R$-module and $M$ has a composition series. How can we conclude that $M$ doesn't have an infinite series of descending submodules? It seems not obvious for me.

Comment: If you're reading a proof that you don't understand, it is better that you point out what part of it you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M$ has an infinite descending chain of submodules $...\subset M_2 \subset M_1 \subset M$. Then, using this infinite chain, you get that the [length of the module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_module) is arbitrarily large. This contradicts the fact that $M$ has a composition series.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  The assumption that $M$ has a composition series means that there is a chain of submodules $0=N_{n}\subset N_{n-1}\subset \cdots\subset N_{1}=M$ and $N_{i+1}$ is maximal in $N_{i}$, but it doesn't say that $M$ can not have a descending submodules series of arbitrary length.  Do I misunderstand the definition of composition series?

Comment: By the Jordan-Hölder Theorem, any composition series of $M$ has the same (finite) length and this length is the maximal possible length of a chain of submodules of $M$ (that's easy to see by definition of composition series) . Thus, by my argument, if there is an infinite chain of submodules, there are arbitrarily long chains of submodules, which contradicts the existence of the composition series.